# Adding Columns to the Model Table using Entity Framework

Tags: sql-server, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-webapi

I created an ASP.NET Core 6 Web API project. After creating the model class, and I did the migrations and all is well. But I deleted the migration file unfortunately.

Now I need to add two new columns the model table, but it show an error while I run the `Update-Database` command

> Error
> There is already an object named 'Movies' in the database.

Model class

```
public class Movie
{
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public int MovieId { get; set; }
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
    public string Genre { get; set; }
    public DateTime ReleaseDate { get; set; }
}
```

I thinks it's trying to create a new table, but I need make changes in the existing table.

Do you have any solution for this situation?

Answer (score 0):

Since you deleted the initial migration, now when you create a new one, the EF doesn't know that the database model already exists partially, so the new migration tries to create the whole DB model from nothing, insted of building upon the previous migration.

To fix this you can run `Update-Database 0` in the Package-Manager console which will reset the database to the empty state.

After that, you apply the new migration with `Update-Database`